# Exception about running out of free space on D:\local\Temp in .Net 6 Web API hosted on Azure App Service (even though there's lots of space)

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, .net-6.0, webapi, azure-appservice

I have a .Net 6 Web API running on Azure App Service (Windows, Standard Service Plan (S1: 1))

Occasionally, I get this exception:

> System.IO.IOException: There is not enough space on the disk. :
> 'D:\local\Temp\ASPNETCORE_7aca67c0-7d1f-40ba-bef3-9e58ea744487.tmp'

This is the stack trace for the last time it happened:

```
System.IO.IOException:
   at System.IO.RandomAccess.WriteAtOffset (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.IO.Strategies.OSFileStreamStrategy.Write (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.IO.Strategies.OSFileStreamStrategy.Write (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities.PagedByteBuffer.MoveTo (Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities.FileBufferingWriteStream.Write (Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities.HttpResponseStreamWriter.Write (Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextWriter.WritePropertyName (Newtonsoft.Json, Version=13.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeObject (Newtonsoft.Json, Version=13.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeList (Newtonsoft.Json, Version=13.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.Serialize (Newtonsoft.Json, Version=13.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.SerializeInternal (Newtonsoft.Json, Version=13.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.NewtonsoftJsonOutputFormatter+<WriteResponseBodyAsync>d__13.MoveNext (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson, Version=6.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.NewtonsoftJsonOutputFormatter+<WriteResponseBodyAsync>d__13.MoveNext (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson, Version=6.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.NewtonsoftJsonOutputFormatter+<WriteResponseBodyAsync>d__13.MoveNext (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson, Version=6.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker+<<InvokeResultAsync>g__Logged|22_0>d.MoveNext (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker+<<InvokeNextResultFilterAsync>g__Awaited|30_0>d`2.MoveNext (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.ResultNext (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeResultFilters (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker+<<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|20_0>d.MoveNext (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker+<<InvokeAsync>g__Logged|17_1>d.MoveNext (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker+<<InvokeAsync>g__Logged|17_1>d.MoveNext (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware+<<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0>d.MoveNext (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at PropWorx.API.Middlewares.TenantIdentifier+<Invoke>d__4.MoveNext (PropWorx.API, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null: C:\Users\fabsr\source\repos\PropWorx.API\PropWorx.API\Middlewares\TenantIdentifier.cs:50)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at PropWorx.API.Middlewares.WebSocketsMiddleware+<Invoke>d__2.MoveNext (PropWorx.API, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null: C:\Users\fabsr\source\repos\PropWorx.API\PropWorx.API\Middlewares\WebSocketsMiddleware.cs:30)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.Policy.AuthorizationMiddlewareResultHandler+<HandleAsync>d__0.MoveNext (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.Policy, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware+<Invoke>d__6.MoveNext (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.Policy, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware+<Invoke>d__6.MoveNext (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session.SessionMiddleware+<Invoke>d__8.MoveNext (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session.SessionMiddleware+<Invoke>d__8.MoveNext (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware+<Invoke>d__5.MoveNext (Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI, Version=6.3.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=4232c99127b3c254)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware+<Invoke>d__4.MoveNext (Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger, Version=6.3.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=62657d7474907593)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware+<Invoke>d__9.MoveNext (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
```

This happens on various API endpoints (i.e. various action methods in various controllers).
The strange thing is that it's happening in methods where I'm not performing any file writing activities. It's simple GET request which performs a basic `SELECT * FROM table` query from a MySql database, and returns the results.

Now, if I go to Azure Portal, and then to my app service, and then to Quotas, I have plenty of free space left:

[image]

If I go to Kudu, and then Environment, I see this:

```
System info

System up time: 12:22:00.1560000
OS version: Microsoft Windows NT 10.0.14393.0
64 bit system: True
64 bit process: True
Processor count: 1
Machine name: RD2818786D33D4
Instance id: eeb07ed981018f5b52e2782779334447fffe71fbeeea9200f63be35f6a12f44a
Short instance id: eeb07e
CLR version: 4.0.30319.42000
System directory: D:\Windows\system32
Current working directory: D:\Program Files (x86)\SiteExtensions\ApplicationInsightsAgent\2.8.43\ExtensionManager
IIS command line: D:\Windows\system32\inetsrv\w3wp.exe -ap "~1propworx-api-san" -v "v4.0" -a "\\.\pipe\iisipmf473d9e2-218c-4cdb-abbe-f3fa8fd44d9a" -h "C:\DWASFiles\Sites\#1propworx-api-san\Config\applicationhost.config" -w "C:\DWASFiles\Sites\#1propworx-api-san\Config\rootweb.config" -m 0
D:\home usage: 51,200 MB total; 47,873 MB free
D:\local usage: 11,264 MB total; 10,894 MB free
```

If you look at the two last lines, I have plenty of space on both *D:\home* and *D:\local*

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you receive a large request perhaps? ASP.NET Core can store large requests to the TEMP folder [as this question shows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62910894/asp-net-core-writes-request-body-to-windows-temp-folder). Your code is running in a VM who's temporary file storage can easily be another mounted virtual disk with limited space that expands based on usage. If you get spammed with a lot of large file POSTs you can end up exhausting that space.

Comment: The solution is not to allocate more space but remove the code that causes the large request to be cached. Perhaps you can disable request caching, or you can change your endpoint code to read from the request stream instead of waiting for the entire body. Do you use HttpClient to make large calls or receive large responses from other services?

Comment: Thanks guys for your responses, and sorry for my late one. @PanagiotisKanavos i read the link you posted, and i will implement that buffering and see if it makes a difference. The strange thing is that, looking at the Azure logs, I've seen that error pop up a number of times on GET requests, not POSTs or PUTs. But it could be ASP .Net Core buffering the response body to a temp file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it is explained here. The solution is to enable buffering on the requests. ASP.NET CORE writes request body to Windows TEMP folder

M$ doc for request buffering. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.httprequestrewindextensions.enablebuffering?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Answer (score 0):

**Your application process experienced a crash. This could be caused by application code.**

---

**Suggestions for Monitoring Crash**

```
Exception Code  
1 crash due to (0xE0434352 - CLR Exception)
```

If the detector below does not have exception details for the crash, suggest the customer to enable Crash Monitoring by following these steps.

1. Go to App Service Diagnostics
2. Choose **Diagnostic Tools** .
3. Click on **Crash Monitoring** from menu options and follow the instructions.

---

**Suggestions for HTTP Server Errors**

```
ExceptionType                              Method                         Count
System.IO.IOException   PropWorx.API.Services.Auth0Service+d__4.MoveNext    5
System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException    PropWorx.API.Middlewares.TenantIdentifier+d__4.MoveNext 3
System.IO.IOException   PropWorx.API.Services.Auth0Service+d__4.MoveNext    2
```

HTTP 500.0 error typically indicates an application code issue. An un-handled exception in the application code or an error in application is what typically causes this error. Please check the code.

---

**The issue I found, please check it in your side**

1. NLog and MySQL, please check it in your Application Exceptions

   ```
   System.AggregateException: An error occurred while writing to logger(s). (Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.)
   ```
2. Slow Request Execution
3. You need to check your `AppInsights`. You can find a lot of exceptions in it.

---

#### Summary

1. please contact your developer Teams, let them review the code according the exceptions.
2. [Enable Local Cache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-local-cache)
3. please read this article, it also will useful to you.

   [The Ultimate Guide to Running Healthy Apps in the Cloud](https://azure.github.io/AppService/2020/05/15/Robust-Apps-for-the-cloud.html)

Comment: What does this have to do with the question? That's just copy pasta of a support page

Comment: Hello @PanagiotisKanavos , There are several posts with the same error, but none of them can give a solution. I did some research and found some useful code error message hints for the op to troubleshoot. I believe this answer can help OP very well. Have a nice day.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I didn't simply paste the support page, from the callstack it can be seen that there are exceptions unhandled in the code (`PropWorx.API.Middlewares.TenantIdentifier+<Invoke>d__4.MoveNext`). I hope you can review this thread. Thanks

Comment: The only thing this answer says is "look at the logs". It doesn't offer any help or fix. What you point to isn't relevant. That's what the call stack of iterators looks like. If you want to tell the OP to check `PropWorx.API.Middlewares.TenantIdentifier`, post a comment. As for NLog, there's nothing in the question or the stack trace that refers to it

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I told the op to check the corresponding information after checking the background log of this webapp. I can't show more because it's a code problem involving the op. My answer, can save the op's time to locate and solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Shortly after posting this question, I deleted all the logs in the LogFiles folder on Azure (I did this via FTP / FileZilla). There were tons of log files going back a long time. I wasn't sure if these contributed towards, what I think could, be a limit on the available temporary storage space, but it's been nearly two weeks, and I haven't had any more "There is not enough space on the disk" exceptions.

I will continue to monitor it. I'm not really sure if this was the fix, but it appears to have helped. I'm half-reluctantly closing this post though as I don't want to keep it open indefinitely.

Thanks to everyone for your input.